# Давать почву чему-то или для чего-то?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Как правильно:

> Эти мысли дают почву для раздумий о мести.

или

> Эти мысли дают почву раздумьям о мести?

Answer (score 3):

В малом академическом словаре:
[**почва**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-academ-term-59688.htm)
**3.** *перен.*
То, на чем зиждется что-либо; основание, основа.
*Чтоб **не давать** ей вперед **почвы для попреков**, Андрей Иванович решил, что с этого дня постарается как можно меньше тратить на самого себя* (В. В. Вересаев. Два конца).

*Oн* [текст] *дoлжeн быть пoнятeн yчaщимcя, вызывaть y ниx интepec и эмoциoнaльный oтклик, paccкaзывaть o чeм-тo нoвoм, **дaвaть пoчвy для paзмышлeний**, нecти вocпитaтeльнyю фyнкцию* ([из статьи](http://orf.textologia.ru/statyi/osobennosti-provedeniya-orfograficheskogo-diktanta/6557/?q=942&n=6557)).

P. S. Предложение, как мне кажется, построено не совсем удачно.
Мысль — это синоним с слову [раздумье](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/4480/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8C%D0%B5) ("мысли дают почву для мыслей").

Answer (score 3):

Не могу сослаться на авторитетный источник, поэтому выскажу собственную точку зрения.

Прямого указания или запрета к употреблению выражения "дать почву (для чего)" или "дать почву (чему)" нигде не указано. Более того, в просмотренных мною 5 фразеологических словарях вообще нет выражения "дать почву", хотя оно, очевидно, является устойчивым.

Похожее выражение "дать пищу" может употребляться в обоих вариантах: чему-либо и для чего-либо. И я считаю, что в этом случае (точно так же, как и в случае с почвой) вопрос управления относится к глаголу **дать**, а не к существительным **пища** и **почва**.

Поиск в гугло-книгах показал, что "давать почву (чему либо)" употребляется значительно реже, но всё же употребляется в добротных источниках (давать почву теориям, мнениям, слухам и т.п.). Намного больше такого рода употреблений обнаруживается в книгах столетней давности, но не только.

Выражение "дать почву слухам" я воспринимаю даже лучше, чем "дать почву для слухов". Но это, пожалуй, единственное исключение (в моём восприятии).

Теперь по самому вопросу.

**Эти мысли дают почву для раздумий о мести.**

Я считаю, что в этом предложении слово "раздумье" является отглагольным существительным, то есть действием, а не результатом действия (иначе предложение выглядит совсем уж плохо). И в этом случае "давать почву для" выглядит единственно возможным вариантом.

Answer (score 1):

**Эти мысли дают почву для раздумий о мести.**

> [ПОЧВА](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B2%D0%B0&all=x), -ы; ж. 2. То, на чём зиждется что-л.; основание, основа. **Благодатная п. для дискуссии.** 3. чего или какая. Область, сфера. **Найти общую почву для разговора.**